# Availability of patent 361, 211

Tags: design

Is this patent expired or still in use? How do I find out if this design patent is still valid

Comment: Design patents are typically valid for 17 years.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the design patent, D361,211: this issued in 1995 and expired 17 years later in 2012. So it's dead and cannot be revived.

http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect2=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&d=PALL&RefSrch=yes&Query=PN/D361211